# WPF Datagrid Rowspan on one column depend of value

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, html-table

(sorry for my english)

I have a problem with my datagrid.

First, my datagrid is fill from a database, depend of a value selected in a combobox. When the SelectedValue of my combobox change the datagrid ItemsSource is refresh with good value.

For now my datagrid look like that

```
|---|---|---|
| A | + | 1 |
|---|---|---|
| A | - | 1 |
|---|---|---|
| B | + | 2 |
|---|---|---|
| C | - | 1 |
|---|---|---|
```

I would like to span row of column with number if letter are equal. Because the value of number is linked to the letter value.

To make the datagris look like

```
|---|---|---|
| A | + |   |
|---|---| 1 |
| A | - |   |
|---|---|---|
| B | + | 2 |
|---|---|---|
| C | - | 1 |
|---|---|---|
```